# Adding option to a product create error

Tags: magento2, custom-options, extend, option

I'm extending the **\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View** file in **AddToCart.php**.

In my AddTocart, I've added this line :

```
$stock = $this->isInStockCustom($sku);
```

Now, I'm adding options to my products. It was working find until now.

But if I add an option to this product, in my log, I have this

> Invalid method
>   Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Interceptor::isInStockCustom [] []

But if I remove the options, I don't have this error anymore.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go it :

also need to change this in **catalog_product_view.xml**:

```
<block class="Vendor\Module\Block\AddToCart" 
name="product.info.addtocart.additional" as="product.info.addtocart" 
template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
```

Because additional option and simple product are not the same.